# ios9: Undefined symbols for architecture arm64

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, ios9.3

I had create framework that using chilkat library and it work fine, then I want to add iSMP.framework to my framework project, I just put .framework into project but it show error like this

[image]

is there any way to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks as if the `get_secret` method might be calling a method from an external library/framework and that framework is not compiled for `arm64`. So you'd have to either get a copy of that framework compiled for `arm64` or change the active architectures for your project to compile the app using the architectures supported by that library.

Comment: I tried to remove arm64 in valid architecture but still not working. the error change to Undefined symbols for architecture arm7

Comment: Do you know which library contains the `get_secret` method and what architectures are supported by that library? I would suggest starting there - find the library, and check it to see what is going on. Or, if you are able to share the project with me, I can take a look and see what is going on.

Comment: I think get_secret method is in iSMP.framework but I already checked every header file and not found that method.

Comment: If that method is not there, then the compiler should throw an error before it gets to the linker stage. So it is probably somewhere. If you can share the project with me, I can take a look. But otherwise, not sure what else to do ...